# How do I disable uninstall button with accessability service in android?

Tags: android, settings, uninstallation, accessibility

I am making a kids app locker and im currently working on the NoRemoval class. It should disable the uninstall button. Bbut I am not receiving any actions whie debugging. Could not figure out why.
And secondly how can I find / disable the uninstall button. I already disabled the clear app data button with this

```xml
android:manageSpaceActivity="com.sec.SpaceManage"
```

but I cant figure out how to disable grey out uninstall button.

```java
package com.sec;

import android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService;
import android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityServiceInfo;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityEvent;
public class NoRemoval extends AccessibilityService {
    private static final String TAG = NoRemoval.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
        Log.i(TAG, "EventType: " + event.getEventType());
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Service Connected");
    }

    @Override
    public void onInterrupt() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

```xml
<service android:name=".NoRemoval"
                android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE"
                android:label="Enable this">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
                </intent-filter>
                <meta-data
                    android:name="android.accessibilityservice"
                    android:resource="@xml/description" />
            </service>
```

Part of manifest.
Now comes "@xml/description":

```xml
<accessibility-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:description="@string/accessibility_service_description"
    android:packageNames="com.sec"
    android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeAllMask"
    android:accessibilityFlags="flagRequestTouchExplorationMode"
    android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackAllMask"
    android:notificationTimeout="1"
    android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
    android:settingsActivity="com.sec.ServiceSettingsActivity"
    />
```